# How to send data from one form to another to create a chart

Tags: c#, windowsformshost

Is it possible to calculate numbers in one form and use it to make a chart in a second form?

I just want to show a line graph which gets the data from a set of numbers being calculated.

I have only been using c# for a week, the only way I know how to make a chart is using `numericUpDown` on the current form which is not what I want.

like so ...

```
Point[] pts = new Point[1000];
int count = 0;

pts[count++] = new Point((int)numericUpDown1.Value, (int)numericUpDown2.Value);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 4), pts[i - 1], pts[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 4), pts[i], pts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code that shows the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data to a new form, and then draw the graph from there. One way would be in the constructor, when you create the new form to draw the graph on, for example:

Form to calculate graph points (or whatever data you need to draw the graph)

```
public class CalculationForm
{
    public CalculationForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Point[] points = CalculatePoints();

        GraphForm graphForm = new GraphForm(points);
        graphForm.Show();
    }

    private Point[] CalculatePoints()
    {
        // method to generate points
        return points;
    }
}
```

Then in the form you want to draw the graph in:

```
public class GraphForm
{
    public GraphForm(Point[] points)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DrawGraph(points);
    }

    private void DrawGraph(Point[] points)
    {
        // Code to draw your graph goes here
    }
}
```